# can't connect to MySQL by old secure_auth

Tags: python, mysql-python

I'm trying make a external connection to MySQL on shared hosting with Python using "MySQLdb.connect" but I get the error:

```
Connection using old (pre-4.1.1) authentication protocol refused (client option 'secure_auth' enabled).
```

It's possible to make a solution for that.

Answer (score 1):

Your options are

1. Connect to a server >=4.1.1 that has secure_auth enabled, or
2. Wait for (or apply) the bug fix http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=75425 or
3. Try one of the workarounds discussed at https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=100831